# Best way to exclude the if's, which in result calls multiple methods

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a form made in JSP, here I have multiple buttons - "Approve, Reject, Save, Cancel".
For every submit, the control goes to a single Controller(Servlet), and there I am handling this submit as ::

```
String methodName = (String) request.getParameter("methodName");
if(methodName.trim.toLower().equals("approve")) 
{
  approve_Claim(parameters);
}
else if(methodName.trim.toLower().equals("reject")) 
{
  reject_Claim(parameters);
}
else if(methodName.trim.toLower().equals("save")) 
{
  save_Claim(parameters);
}
else if(methodName.trim.toLower().equals("cancel")) 
{
  cancel_Claim(parameters);
}
```

Is there a way to remove these multiple if's, 
please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you basically want a mapping from `methodName.trim().toLower()` to some sort of "claim action" which takes parameters. Create an interface like this:

```
interface ClaimAction
{
    void execute(Parameters parameters);
}
```

Then implement this with classes of `CancelClaimAction`, `ApproveClaimAction` etc. Next create a `Map<String, ClaimAction>` mapping "approve" to an `ApproveClaimAction` etc. Then:

```
String actionName = methodName.trim().toLower(Locale.US));
ClaimAction action = CLAIM_ACTION_MAPPING.get(actionName);
if (action != null)
{
    action.execute(parameters);
}
else
{
    // Error case, presumably.
}
```

You *could* use enums to do this, but I'd *expect* each of these classes to have enough work to do that it's worth separating them out and testing each one individually.

Comment: just curious to know:  this looks some how similar to Factory pattern to me. Can we state same with factory pattern?

Comment: @HarryJoy: It's more like the strategy pattern than the factory pattern. We're not really *creating* anything, so I don't see how it's factory-like. Unless you're thinking that the map itself is the factory, which is a bit of a stretch IMO.

Comment: You mean this: [Strategy_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), right? Didn't know about it, thought me something new, Thanks.

Comment: @HarryJoy: Yes, that's what I meant. Whether it's an entirely appropriate name for what's going on here is a different matter, as the purpose of each action is different. I try not to get too hung up on patterns though to be honest - I try to use them as a starting place for ideas, rather than trying to analyze all the code I write and put it in buckets. They were great when first written up, but I think they've been over-emphasized a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives coming in my minds are with switch statement:

1. Pass integers instead of strings in parameter, parse them to int in servlet and then use switch case on this integers.
2. If you are using Java 7 then use switch case over string.
3. <del>In java 6</del> take Enum of this strings and then switch over them - for older versions, upto java 5, (as Enum are introduced in java 5, mentioned by Jon skeet)

Comment: Enums were introduced in Java 5, not Java 6.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm just saying that if he is not using java 7 and using java 6. Cause most of out there uses Java 6.

Comment: But why limit it artificially? Why explicitly state "Java 6" with the *implication* that if you're using Java before 6, you can't use enums?

Answer (score 0):

The comparison about wich action was triggered has to be done somewhere. You can remove this logic from this place by using maybe something like this

```
public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String action){}
```

but as i said , the validation has to come somewhere in your code....

Answer (score 0):

Well first suggestion will be that you can re-think on the  approach itself. Lots of MVC frameworks are out there (like struts, struts2, spring MVC, play framework) which does all the handling part for you keeping you actual code very simple and clean.

---

Assuming you have some specific purpose to use your own implementation I would suggest you can use java reflection for this.

```
String methodName = (String) request.getParameter("methodName");
this.getClass().getMethod(methodName).invoke(this);
```

What you need to do here, is keep the methodNames same as the acutal java methods.

To pass the parameters, you can do it this way -

```
String methodName = (String) request.getParameter("methodName");
this.getClass().getMethod(methodName, Paramter.class).invoke(this, parameters);
```